# Apply normal mode command to regex matches

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I am using the following regular expression to match a documentation string underneath a Clojure function definition:

```
\vdefn.*\n\s*\zs"([^"]|\n)*"
```

Is there a way to run the normal mode `gq` (format lines) command on all matches of this pattern in a given file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Power of `g`:

```
:g/\vdefn.*\n\s*\zs"([^"]|\n)*"/normal gngq
```

The part between the `/`s is fairly self-explanatory, since it's the regex from your original question.

`normal gngq` at the end is somewhat interesting. `gn` will select the next match of the regular expression, and `gq`, of course, formats this selection (as you mentioned in your question).

`:g` is the really great part. This is, in my opinion, one of Vim's most useful features. The `g` ex command takes a regex and an Ex command, and it executes the command on every line the regex matches. If you haven't learned about `:g` already, I highly recommend doing so, as it'll vastly increase your productivity. A few resources are Vim's own `:help :g` or [Power of g](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) on Vim wiki.

Comment: The `gn` piece is selecting from the line where `V` is triggered to the *next* (not the one on the same line) occurrence of the pattern. Vim's documentation states that if visual mode is active, the selection is extended from the current line through the next pattern. This is causing unwanted behavior.

Comment: @merb Whoops, didn't realize that. Edited.

Comment: The selection is still from the line of the match to the *next* match. Stepping through the normal mode commands manually shows that `//s<cr>` leaves me at the beginning of the match on the current line, but `//e<cr>` leaves me at the end of the next match, not the current match.

Comment: @merb Huh, that's strange. It works for me (even with `vim -u NONE`). Are you perhaps running this command while already on the first match? You should enter this from the beginning of the file.

Comment: Yes, I am running it from the top of the file. I tested it with `vim -u NONE` and it doesnt work there either.. my Vim version is `7.4` if that makes any difference.

Comment: The problem appears to be with `//s<cr>V`. When I run `:normal V` I go into visual line mode, as expected. When I run `:normal //s<cr>` my cursor lands on the first `"` of the match, as expected. When I run `:normal //s<cr>V` I do not get a visual selection.

Comment: Solved it. The command needs to be `normal gngq`. Suggesting an edit.

Comment: @merb Ah, thanks. (Sorry for not responding to your comments earlier; I had to leave.)